# DDL Triggers invoked on DROP COLUMN in Oracle 11.2.0.4.0

Tags: oracle, triggers

If you run the following code snippet below the trigger on the table is invoked when a clumn is dropped which had been added after the table creation and has a default value and not null defined. This is behaviour I could only reproduce in Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 but not in 11.2.0.3.0. COuld somebody please help me with this? Is this expected behaviour? How can I drop the column without running the trigger?

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(50)
);

INSERT INTO T (DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('asd');

COMMIT;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BEFORE_T_U
    BEFORE UPDATE ON T
    REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003, 'This before update trigger should not be invoked!');
END BEFORE_T_U;
/

ALTER TABLE T ADD AMOUNT NUMBER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE T DROP COLUMN AMOUNT;
```

Comment: have you tried ALTER TRIGGER name DISABLE?

Comment: Could not reproduce on  12c. Make three seperate triggers for insert, update, delete with corresponding error text and see wich DML the DDL executes.

Comment: @PaulKienitz I would like to avoid the update on the table rows. This issue is happening for me on a table with millions of rows and disabling the trigger is not an option.

Comment: @RobertMerkwürdigeliebe The trigger for the update is executed. Modified the code snippet to have an uopdate only trigger.

Comment: Not reproduced on 11.2.0.3.0. DML triggers should never fire on DDL statements, so if this is reproducible it would be strange.